# Java AmazonS3 putObject fails silently

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

Others have posted about this without receiving an answer and now I'm experiencing this same issue. Actually it has been going on for 9 months but I'm just now noticing it.

This sequence does not throw an exception and the message at the end is logged:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
String bucket = "...";
String key = "...";
File f = new File("...");
PutObjectResult r = s3.putObject(bucket, key, f);
String etag = r.getETag();
LOGGER.info("file ... saved with etag = "+etag);
```

The file is not present in the bucket when I look.

This fails a few dozen times a day out of thousands of files posted. There are 25 active threads using this sequence of code. Is aws-java-sdk thread safe? Other ideas?

This is running on an ec2 instance in the amazon cloud.

Details:

```
aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.693.jar
java: 1.8.0_201-b09
ubuntu: 4.4.0-1077-aws
```

Comment: *"This sequence does not throw an exception and the message at the end is logged."*  Sounds impossible.  I don't know enough Java to even use the right terminology but the thread has to still be running, blocking, waiting on something, doesn't it?  It can't fail to progress to the log line and also not throw an exception.  Are you leaking/losing track of threads?  My point is, "fails silently" seems like an inaccurate characterization of what you are experiencing because what's the state of the thread after, and how did that log line get skipped?  It sounds instead like a "hung" condition.

Comment: literally the log statement is executed and the log entry is written and the file does not exist in the bucket. that's how i know it doesn't throw an exception. hence the phrase, "fails silently".

Comment: Wow, I need to learn to read.  I incorrectly saw *the message at the end is* ***not*** *logged* ... so "fails silently" is correct.

Comment: Turn on logging for your bucket and see what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-) say: "Amazon S3 never stores partial objects; if during this call an exception wasn't thrown, the entire object was stored". So, I think, there are two questions: 1) Does the file you're trying to upload exist? Does it have any content? 2) Where the hell it is actually aploaded? Print the `putObject` result and carefully study it's content.

Comment: …I mean, does the file (`f`) exists on your local machine, where you run this code?

Comment: uh, not a dope. yes file exists, yes, has content. the putobjectresult has an etag, some other stuff, nothing like a transaction id that could be used to trace the calls.

Comment: I saw the exact same thing on a 27MB file. When I pushed it using `AmazonS3.putObject` it would return a `PutObjectResult` that said the put resulted in a 0 byte object per `result.getMetadata().getContentLength()`. When I changed the code to use "multi-part" upload using 5MB parts, it finally started working correctly and uploading the file: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue when uploading a 27MB file using `AmazonS3.putObject`. The command returned a `PutObjectResult` but there was no S3 object in the expected location and the result metadata (`result.getMetadata().getContentLength()`) showed 0 bytes. I fixed this by using multi-part upload per [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html).

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(S3Handler.class);
private static final long MAX_SINGLE_PART_UPLOAD_BYTES = 5 * 1024 * 1024;

private final AmazonS3 amazonS3;

public S3Handler(AmazonS3 amazonS3) {
    this.amazonS3 = amazonS3;
}

public void putS3Object(String bucket, String objectKey, File file) {
    if (file.length() <= MAX_SINGLE_PART_UPLOAD_BYTES) {
        putS3ObjectSinglePart(bucket, objectKey, file);
    } else {
        putS3ObjectMultiPart(bucket, objectKey, file);
    }
}

private void putS3ObjectSinglePart(String bucket, String objectKey, File file) {
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, objectKey, file);
    PutObjectResult result = amazonS3.putObject(request);
    long bytesPushed = result.getMetadata().getContentLength();
    LOGGER.info("Pushed {} bytes to s3://{}/{}", bytesPushed, bucket, objectKey);
}

private void putS3ObjectMultiPart(String bucket, String objectKey, File file) {
    long contentLength = file.length();
    long partSize = MAX_SINGLE_PART_UPLOAD_BYTES;
    List<PartETag> partETags = new ArrayList<>();

    // Initiate the multipart upload.
    InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(bucket, objectKey);
    InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse = amazonS3.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);

    // Upload the file parts.
    long fileOffset = 0;
    for (int partNumber = 1; fileOffset < contentLength; ++partNumber) {
        // Because the last part could be less than 5 MB, adjust the part size as needed.
        partSize = Math.min(partSize, (contentLength - fileOffset));

        // Create the request to upload a part.
        UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                .withBucketName(bucket)
                .withKey(objectKey)
                .withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId())
                .withPartNumber(partNumber)
                .withFileOffset(fileOffset)
                .withFile(file)
                .withPartSize(partSize);

        // Upload the part and add the response's ETag to our list.
        UploadPartResult uploadResult = amazonS3.uploadPart(uploadRequest);
        LOGGER.info("Uploading part {} of Object s3://{}/{}", partNumber, bucket, objectKey);
        partETags.add(uploadResult.getPartETag());

        fileOffset += partSize;
    }

    // Complete the multipart upload.
    CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(bucket, objectKey, initResponse.getUploadId(), partETags);
    amazonS3.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest);
}
```